# regular expression to find a repeated code

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a reg expression to find match of strings / code in a database.

here is some of the sample code / string which i need to remove using the regular expression.

```
[b:1wkvatkt] 
[/b:1wkvatkt]
[b:3qo0q63v]
[/b:3qo0q63v]
[b:2r2hso9d]
[/b:2r2hso9d]
```

Anything that match [b:********]  and [/b:********]

Anybody please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: If you're trying to do this with SQL then you'll have to tell what kind of database you use.  Since regex stuff isn't part of standard ANSI SQL. Anyway, a regex to match those : `\[\/?b:[a-z0-9]+\]`

Comment: it works \[\/?b:[a-z0-9]+\]  thanks !

Comment: What do i need to do if i want to replace the pattern [b:********] and [/b:********]  with <b>  and </b>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern (as stated by LukStorms in the comments):

```
\[\/?b:[a-z0-9]+\]
```

If you want to replace `[b:********]` with `<b>` (and also the closing one), you can use the following snippet (here in JavaScript, other languages are similar):

```js
var regex = /\[(\/)?b:[a-z0-9]+\]/g;
var testText = "There was once a guy called [b:12a345]Peter[/b:12a345]. He was very old.";

var result = testText.replace(regex, "<$1b>");
console.log(result);
```

It matches an optional `/` and puts it into the first group (`$1`). This group can then be used in the replacement string. If the slash is not found, it won't be added, but if it is found, it will be added to `<b>`.